# Creating Custom Dialog Box

Tags: customdialog, framemaker

I have installed FDK2019(32-bit) and Framemaker2019(32-bit) and created a new DRE file from the existing DRE files in FDK Directory. When i am going to save it as abc.dre the framemaker gives following error:

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround solution: try to open a ".dre" file (don't use a ".dre" file as a template to create a new one), then make the changes you want and save the file without any problem.